# AS2 call function inside movieclip

Tags: actionscript-2, movieclip

I have a movieClip with a few animations and a layer for actionscript code.
What I need to do is to call a function that is defined in MovieClip from "Scene 1".

I've tried many combination without success:
_root.mc1.teste();
mc1.teste();
this.mc1.teste();
parent.mc1.teste();

At this moment, movie clip is located on "Stage 1" and it has instance name "mc1". I also have tried to create the same movie clip dynamicly with "attachMovie" but the problem remains.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**
As you can see on the image below. I have some functions defined in Layer3 on a frame1 and I want to call them from Scene1).

[image]
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are both your clips on stage?

Debugging Tip: Try to trace each clip so you know that you are targeting them correctly.

```
// Inside each clip, trace it's own path
trace(this);
```

This way, you can discover the actual path that needs to be used.